# Removing case for HP ElitePad 1000 G2 Rugged

Tags: tablet, case

I just received a HP ElitePad 1000 G2 Rugged to test my software on and I was looking to remove the case it comes with. All pictures I see of the ElitePad 1000 looks slim, so that leads me to believe that this case can be removed but I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Does anyone have an idea on how I can remove this case?

Tablet w/ Case -- http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/products/tablets/product-detail.html?oid=7468174

Tablet w/o Case -- http://www.vortez.net/news_file/5980_hp.jpg

Comment: Dumb question but maybe the Elitepad 1000 and the Elitepad 1000 G2 Rugged are different models?

Comment: Have you tried taking the screws out?

Comment: This video shows how to open the case [HP ElitePad - Serviceability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urKcp_WaFwo)

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yes I tried that and it still acts like it should not come off.

Comment: @DavidPostill I will check out the video. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPostill That doesn't even have the rugged case on it. They are taking the screen off